# using jquery to get the content of a <tag>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, dom

I have a question regarding "unknown" tags. I mean tags that are not defined in HTML.

See the following block:

```
<div class='container'>
  <element definition>
</div>
```

And then using jquery I want to get the list of all div's children and then extract their content. To achieve this, I don't know if I have only RegExp to do, or there are some jQuery functions to get.

For instance, defining a function `set_tags_to_p()` that changes the tags to `<p>`.

Comment: You could use this $("#container").text() to get the text contents of all the tags.. and traverse the children even if they are not standard with $("#container").children().each(function() { ... });

Comment: It seems you're asking for two different things, may I ask you to clarify? Did you mean to ask about 1. tree traversal when tags are not standard, or 2. how to write the function `set_tags_to_p()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace children elements with `p` pretty easy like this:

```
$('.container').children().replaceWith(function() {
    return '<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>';
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F73cS/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container').find('*').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XFckE/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var element, elementHtml, pTag;
element = $("element") // you can change the name
elementHtml = element.html();
pTag = $("<p>").html(elementHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the tags you want to replace, you could just do:

```
<div class="container">
    <up>Test</up>
    <down>Test</down>
    <left>Test</left>
    <right>Test</right>
    <broken>Test</broken>
</div>

$(function(){
  $('.container').children("up, down").replaceWith(function() {
    return '<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>';
  });      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JqY5R/